# GetwindowoffsetEx in windows XP and up

Tags: c++, windows

I have an visaul object up and running
GetwindowoffsetEx moved the canvas around

But I cannot change the size of the canvas to my needs

Like should I not beable to change the canvas size for a A4-A3 printer or to a picture size
can this be done using the windows API
I do not seem to get the instructions to do this.

I take it that if I want a Zoom, I strech draw from another cavuas

am I asking the obvious in all this.

Lex Dean

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand exactly what I need but you seem to want to [map between two coordinate spaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183475%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in GDI.

Whilst you can use the fully general [`SetWorldTransform()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145104%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), I suspect you are better off with the following functions:

- [`SetWindowOrgEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145101%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [`SetWindowExtEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145100%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [`SetViewportOrgEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145099%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`SetViewportExtEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145098%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

The MSDN documentation also includes a full [list of functions related to coordinate space transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145098%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).